# Automatically run VBA macro whenever a cell value changes

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, vba

I have a macro that works perfectly - except that I have to manually run it.
I cannot figure out how to have it automatically run when I change values in other cells.

```
Sub MonthlyMaintHideRowsWithZeroDollars()

' This Macro reads down the dollar column and hides rows with $0 
' so that they do not pull into the proposal

    If Range("B7").Value = "Hide" Then
        Rows("7:7").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("B7").Value = "Show" Then
        Rows("7:7").EntireRow.Hidden = False    
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the [`Worksheet_change`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff839775.aspx) event

> Occurs when cells on the worksheet are changed by the user or by an external link.

#### Example

```
Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    If Range("B7").Value = "Hide" Then
        Rows("7:7").EntireRow.Hidden = True
    ElseIf Range("B7").Value = "Show" Then
        Rows("7:7").EntireRow.Hidden = False    
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: **Help** 
This works when I run it, but does not automatically run when a linked cell changes.   I am stuck.  Thanks, Ed

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub

Sub MonthlyMaintHideRowsWithZeroDollars() ' ' MonthlyMaintHideRowsWithZeroDollars Macro ' Macro row with $0  '

If Range("B3").Value = "Hide" Then
    Rows("3:3").EntireRow.Hidden = True
ElseIf Range("B3").Value = "Show" Then
    Rows("3:3").EntireRow.Hidden = False
    End If
      
End Sub

Comment: @EdRegis You have to insert your IF-statement between the `sub` and `end sub` part. I edited the post

Comment: I tried what you suggested - the macro still works when I run it manually
It just does not want to run automatically when I type  **Hide** into B7
?????

Perhaps there is an option that I have to turn of to have the macros run automatically beyond:
**Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
End Sub**